# difference between resource and controller generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when I do

```
rails g model user name:string
rails g controller users index create new destroy show
```

and edit config/routes.rb to add:

```
resource :users
```

bundle exec rake routes gives:

```
     users POST   /users(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_users GET    /users/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
           GET    /users(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
           PUT    /users(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
           DELETE /users(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

however, when I do

```
rails g resource users name:string
```

(which automatically adds resources :users to config/routes.rb) 
    bundle exec rake routes

I get

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

So my question is,

when I generate a controller how can I get the correct helper methods to make
link_to 'Destroy', instance, :method=> :delete 
work?

Because currently it gives an error user_path is not defined.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes.rb file in both cases for the user resource? Also, please separate commands with line breaks for clarity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call

```
rails g controller user index create new destroy show
```

instead of

```
rails g controller users index create new destroy show
```

in order to get `resources :users` to give you the helpers you want.

The latter causes Rails to assume that `users` is a singular object, and that `resources :users` should create what is called a singular resource:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

as a result, `user_path` is undefined, whereas `users_path` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `rails g controller` and specify the method names, the generator only maps specific routes to the routes file. `rails g resource` assumes that you want the whole resource functionality and will map `resources`.

In order to fix this, just go into your routes file and replace the specific mappings with a resources call.

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

What I really wanted was a way of creating a working (with correct delete/show paths) controller for an existing model (as described in the question) but just adding "resource :x" and generating the controller wasn't enough.

I ended up using the scaffold_controller generator. It doesn't create any migrations or models, but it does generate a resource with views and `rake paths` command shows the correct paths for delete and show to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following commands in the console:

```
$rails g model user name:string
$rails g scaffold_controller User
```

And add this code line to the file routes.rb:

```
resources :users
```