# What's the difference between controllers and actions in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, action, controllers

Can anybody tell me the difference between controllers and actions in ruby on rails?

I fetched this definition from the official rails guide:

> A controller's purpose is to receive specific requests for the application. Routing decides
>   which controller receives which requests. Often, there is more than one route to each
>   controller, and different routes can be served by different actions. Each action's purpose is
>   to collect information to provide it to a view.

I am confused.
Please, make it as simple as possible since I am newbie!

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link to the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: take the help from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216722/difference-between-resource-and-controller-generators

Comment: This is very confusing HarsHarl. Too much code! I am looking for a bit of an 'abstract' explanation. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Yeah, I ran into those two paragraph under 4.2 "Hello Rails" and read them over and over. They are extremely confusing and unclear, but I knew they hold the most crucial big-picture information. This thread is invaluable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Controllers are just [Ruby Class](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_classes.html) files which have a series of [instance methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) inside

---

**Basic Explanation**

Rails controllers are basically files where actions (methods) are kept

Each time you access a Rails app, you're sending a request to the system. The various technologies inside Rails `route` that request to a certain `action`, where your code can use the passed data to perform some sort of `action` (hence the name). The actions are kept inside `controllers` to give the application structure

So if you access `http://yourapp.com/users/new`, it tells Rails to load the `new` method in the `users` controller. You can have as many actions in the controllers as you want, but you have to tell the Rails `routes` system they are there, otherwise they won't be accessible

---

**Proper Explanation**

Rails `Controllers` are just Ruby Classes, storing a series of actions

The "actions" (instance methods) work on passed data ([`params`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained)) to create [objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm) that can either be passed to the model, or used inside other methods

Whenever you send a request to Rails (access a URL), it first uses the [ActionDispatch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) middleware to send your request to the correct Class (`controller`) instance method (`action`), and then your code does something with that data

Your job as a dev is to connect the right controllers with the right models, presenting the right data the user at the right time

Comment: No problem - it's an incredible system to learn, but the more you find out, the more growth you can see! How long have you been developing RoR for?

Comment: Because your question is generic - SO is really for specific programming questions (the more code, the better). I'll upvote you again

Comment: *it tells Rails to load the `new` function in the `users` controller*-- not a function..It is a method. :) :) Be Rubyish..

Comment: Thanks a heap! I am very new to RoR! And to programming in general. I am very grateful Rich!

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry buddy - I've used several languages, so `function` is just my way of explaining :)

Comment: A great big picture explanation for noobs like me that need some idea of how it all works.  A+ thank you

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't write code in Rails (never did). I write [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) modular applications and use the MVC model.

You first need to clarify the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model. The MVC is an approach to programming web applications (in RoR) or user interfaces in general. So **MVC** stands for **Model-View-Controller**. I will try to explain a bit, but in order to understand this, you need to practice and play with it.

- **The Model**: If you remove the layers of abstraction, it's your database scheme. The way your application interconnects in order to retrieve information.
- **The View**: The way these informations are retrieved elaborated and **served**. Essentially is what you, or the client, see in the browser.
- **The Controller**: The controller is what interacts with the program to produce a requested view or to alter a model. You request a view when you access a chart with statistical information, and you alter the model when you input DATA on it. In Rails ecosystem, **ActionController** is a **class** with a set of predefined methods to help you perform easier and quicker standard Controller actions like update a form, etc.

So the **Action Controller** allows you to alter data to your models (the db), or request a *route* to **view** your data, etc.

Action is not separated from **controllers**, it's basically what **controllers** do :-). Everything else is *static*.

If you feel that these concepts are still hard to grasp, try building a very basic modular application in Sinatra, and you will have a ground level view of how things work.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation by Analogy (simple explanation without getting too technical)

I work in a busy office. I bark out orders (i.e. 'requests') to my staff to get em to do stuff.

e.g.

Sometimes I want a document so I can read it.

> “Ngozi, pass me the ABC.ASX EOFY results please?”

Yes sir!

Sometimes I ask my staff to edit an existing document:

> “Sunita, can you edit that report on the state of the union address?”

“Sure!” is the response.

#### I organise my staff based on the type of work they do

But I have a little problem.....I have 10,000s of different types of documents. Sometimes I want to get: (I) sports results and other times I want: (ii) the evening news, while still at other times I want: (iii) a collection of Donald Trump's latest 4 am Tweets.

So I created a new system. I have a staff member directly responsible for each type of thing.

- Ngozi handles ASX (Australian Stock Exchange) Financial Results. And when I want Ngozi to do something (i.e. perform some type of action) then I tell him what to do.
- Sunita works mainly on politics. Sometimes I”ll ask her to something (e.g. write up a report – this is one type of 'action', or I'll ask her to bring me a certain document – another type of action - and she'll do it. I like to get Sunita to work on politics and Ngozi to work on financial results. It's best to keep their responsibilities separated.).
- And Freddie works on anything pertaining to Queen.

Etc. etc.

### The meaning of the analogy?

In this case, the controller would be the person – who's responsible for handling certain types of requests. And the “action” would be the particular specific thing that I want done:

e.g.

- getting a document or
- edit something or even
- creating a new document.

Hope that clears things up.